# How to make model's arms + weapon follow cursor?

Tags: models, skeletal-animation

0
Just like the title says. I currently have my controlling movement working just how I want it to. Now in order to proceed with shooting I first should focus on how the model should look like to determine how my script should act when firing. Currently I am using Unity's Constructor model, but now I need to create my own model just to get the arm movements to follow how I want it to. I have an idea how to make the arms follow the cursor, by adjusting the X and Y axis rotation to follow the position of the cursor, taking on screen coordinates then using Atan to find the right angle. First I have no idea how to make a model, so I guess I need to figure that out first, but how can I make it move like the constructor model from Unity. I have heard of rigging, but still not sure what that is. I have played with C4D when in high school which I noticed while modeling it help provide a human like effect when controlling joints. I am planning on using Blender so if anyone had 3D modeling humanoids video with rigging or skeletal joint or something. Not an artist at all, but I need a model I suppose.

This is a 2.5D platform game, 3D environment with 2D physics.

Comment: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/14290 - if you don't use unity then you get the idea of what you should be looking for

Answer (score 1):

What I suggest is to have a right where the arms and weapon bones all follow the same inverse kinematic target. This ars-and-weapons IK target is in turn parented to the global ik target. For example if you're using Blender use some "Empty" objects for the IK targets.

Then in unity just have the arms-and-weapon IK target point towards the mouse when needed. This way your over-all IK target will be controlled by the player controller (and move yoru whose character around) and furthermore, when the mouse cursor moves, the arms-and-weakpon IK target will keep pointing towards them while at the same time also having the transformations for the global IK applied to it (ie if the character is moving forwards and the mouse is somewhere to the right, the character will keep advancing but his arms and weapon will keep facing the cursor).

You might also want to add some transform constrains on the transformation of the arms-and-weapon IK target (or the bone it ifluences) such that the player's arms don't gen in non-humanly-possible postures.